# Wordpress multisite apply different options over each site from same plugin

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I created a plugin for the bootstrap navbar. Then I created an option page for my plugin.  In my options page, I have two types of navbar (Default navbar and Full-width navbar) you can only choose one of them. I want to use WordPress multisite and create two sites within it. Then in the first site show the Default navbar and, in the second site, show the full-width navbar. Can I can activate the same plugin in each site and use different options in each site? Or must I install WordPress two times then using the plugin in each WordPress installation folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the plugin in the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory.  Each site in your network has its own `_options` table in the database so as long as you are using built-in WP functions for handling your plugin's options, each site will have its own distinct set of options.

Comment: Does it need to be a `mu-plugin`? And probably worth spelling out you mean `add_option`, `update_option`, `get_option`, not the `_site_` versions.

Comment: doesn't have to be mu, but he said he wants it activated in each site...so easy enough to just put it there.